# cannot resolve '`abx-abc-123.A1.OP`' given input columns: [abx-abc-123.A1.OP,column2,column3]

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I have a column named in this structure - 'abx-abc-123.A1.OP'

but when I run this command

```
    final_merged_df.select('abx-abc-123.A1.OP')
```

I'm getting 'cannot resolve '`abx-abc-123.A1.OP`' given input columns: [abx-abc-123.A1.OP,column2,column3]' error.

Comment: Just use ```final_merged_df.select(col("`abx-abc-123.A1.OP`"))```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add these marks around such column names

```
final_merged_df.select('`abx-abc-123.A1.OP`')
```